# UITextField for nickname

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I need to set UITextField for nickname. It need to be english only, lowercase, underscore and numbers. Really don't know how to do that and can't find any information. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you mean placeholder?

Comment: Drag one into View Controller in your storyboard.

Comment: If someone will try to make nickname with russian language or with "%" - alert will tell that it is not match. How to filtrate textfield by values:  english only, lowercase, underscore and numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a regex for this & comparison textfield value with your regex pattern.

```
func isValidName(name:String)-> Bool {
    let nameRegEx = "^[a-z0-9_]+$" // this mean you can only use lower case a-z, 0-9 and underscore
    let namelTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", nameRegEx)
    return namelTest.evaluate(with: name)
}
```

use this method and vaidate textfield value by pasting as parameter function.

if return true it means username passed validation.

if return false you can show an error to user or shake textfiled and set red color for textfield.text or placeholder color or any thing you want.

hope to this help you.